# Updating a feature branch from master - x commits ahead?

Tags: git, github, merge

Disclaimer: I am still obviously inexperienced with Git.  Thank you for your help and patience.

Occasionally, after working in a "feature" branch for some time, I'll want to pull in new changes from master.  Let's say that the feature branch is x commits behind master.  When I update the feature branch, the git tools I use (e.g. SourceTree, GitHub (when pushed), etc.) report that I have just created x new commits on my feature branch.

Ultimately, the history only shows a single merge commit.  However, odd things happen as a result of these "x" commits.  For example, when I push the branch, a post is made to our Slack channel (generated via GitHub) claiming that I have just added y commits (where y=x+[the number of new, non-merge-related commits present in the feature branch])

For example, I have just merged master into my feature branch, and SourceTree now shows that I have 97 commits ready to be pushed.  (Before the merge, SourceTree only showed that I had 2 unpushed commits):

[image]

Is this normal?  Is git/SourceTree effectively just "referencing" the original commits instead of duplicating the relevant code changes in a brand new commit?

None of this is really a big deal, but it is a bit misleading and confusing.  Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of merging master into your feature, you should be rebasing your feature onto master. This assumes that you have not pushed your changes yet.

```
git fetch <remote>
git checkout <feature>
git rebase <remote>/master
```

This will make sure that you push **your** commits only.

Comment: Like you implied - if I've already pushed to GitHub, things may be different.  Everything I've read seems to be summed up as, "If you haven't pushed to any public repositories, do a rebase.  If you *have* pushed, do a merge."  Any thoughts on what I should do if I've already pushed?

Comment: @rinogo This is not an absolute rule, just a suggestion. The reason is that if anyone else fetched your commit, he/she will need to fetch with the -f (force) option to get your new changes. This issue can be solved by just informing them to force fetch. Even worse, though, is if someone started working off your changes. In this case, he/she will have commits that are basically a duplicate, but Git does not know that. You can solve this with `git rebase --onto <your-new-commit> <last-unneeded-commit>`, but this can get very confusing, with a large number of committers.

Answer (score -1):

Just in case others have same question in the future. Following is a possible approach.

1. Create a new branch  from master. This new branch will contain a copy of latest files in master.
2. Merge  branch to .
3. Continue to work on